# Two Facebook Like Buttons Wrong Counts

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have `two` Facebook like buttons on my page. One is "`fan like`" the other is regular "`like`" Both are using iframes. First one has about 100 likes the other has been recently added.

After adding the correct meta attributes the new like button still uses the `wrong url`.

URL linter displays all data correctly `EXCEPT` the Like Button at the end (where you can copy source) shows 1000 likes vs 0-5 for the new button. On the site the new buttons shows the wrong count.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know Facebook uses for each Like Button you generate a new app id. You can check this if you generate a new button for the same URL.
Make sure that the buttons are using the same app id which you can check here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps or here https://www.facebook.com/insights/